# How to get line and read store them into an array

Tags: c, linux

I really need some help with C programming.  I know how to do this task in C++ but I need to do it in C this time.

Object:
So I want to have a program that would read strings from stdin then print them using different Format Specifiers.

Problem :
I try to read strings separated by 'white space' and store them into an array which allows them to be printed 'separately'.

The main issue here is I do not know how to store them like what we might do in C++, e.g. have an array then you store them like `str[i] == str_read` and use `cout << str[i]<<endl` to print.

If we read in a string of hex numbers and output as ASCII

The input will look like this: `0x72 0x6f 0x6c`

The output would be  `r o l`

edit :
I got this code from Internet that could read whole line.  What I need is to pull these strings like `"0x72" "0x6f"` out and put them into array separately.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int input(char *s, int length);

int main()
{
   char *buffer;
  size_t bufsize = 32;
  size_t characters;

buffer = (char *)malloc(bufsize * sizeof(char));
if (buffer == NULL)
{
    perror("Unable to allocate buffer");
    exit(1);
}

printf("Type something: ");
characters = getline(&buffer, &bufsize, stdin);
printf("%zu characters were read.\n", characters);
printf("You typed: '%s'\n", buffer);

return(0);
```

}

Comment: Wrap a loop around the scanner and the printer.

Comment: you need a loop to keep accepting input

Comment: "*store them into an array*" the code shown does not, not even is trying to.

Comment: alk you r right,this code is irreverent to this problem. could you post some examples on how to " loop to keep accepting input" in C or links if possible? it's been really confusing.

Comment: Off-topic for this question, but don't use `scanf_s` or `printf_s`.  They're no safer than the standard `scanf()` and `printf()` functions, and they're not portable.  Per http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1967.htm: "Microsoft Visual Studio implements an early version of the APIs. However, the implementation is incomplete and conforms neither to C11 nor to the original TR 24731-1. ...  As a result of the numerous deviations from the specification the Microsoft implementation cannot be considered conforming or portable. "

Comment: If the question is about parsing whitespace-delimited substrings from a string, then consider using [`strtok()` or `strtok_r()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html).

Comment: And don't cast the result of `malloc` & friends or `void *` in general. Also `sizeof(char)` is useless, it can't be anything else than `1`)

Comment: regarding: `buffer = (char *)malloc(bufsize * sizeof(char));
if (buffer == NULL)
{
    perror("Unable to allocate buffer");
    exit(1);
}`  all this can be replaced with `char *buffer = NULL;`  as the POSIX function: `getline()` always does its' own memory allocaton

Comment: The returned type from `getline()` is `ssize_t`  which is a signed value so a format specifier of `%zu` is not correct.  Also, the code needs to be checking the returned value (>0) to assure the operation was successful.